# How to Create and Fire HTML Video tag Events

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events

I have come across a weird requirement, where I need to create a HTML video tag event like Play, Pause, VolumeChanged etc and then fire them, as it will be handled by a different module.

Is there any way where this can be done similar to `CreateCustomEvent` or `CreateEvent` and `Dispatch` Event?

I searched in net, but could not find any help except for directly calling `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play()` etc but this is not what I need, because I want the registered event handler to handle the events once fired. But directly calling play() will actually play the video along with firing the 'play' event.

So please help me out...

Comment: Yup. I believe this is what you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Instead of doing document.dispatchEvent dispatch the events directly on video element as shown below.

```
function()
{
var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var VideoEvent = new Event('play');
videoElement.dispatchEvent(VideoEvent);
}
```

and on application side have handler as shown below:

```
function onload() 
{
video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
video.addEventListener('play', handleVideoEvent, false);
video.addEventListener('pause', handleVideoEvent, false);
}

function handleVideoEvent(evt)
{
    alert('Handle event ' + evt.type);
}
```

Please let me know any links or docs explaining about event handling in browsers. I thought since video will be a child node of document element, the event might be propagated from document to video, but it does not. Instead the events bubble up from child node to parent.
Its confusing!!!!

Anyways

Thanks for Help guys.